# Android and supporting Multiscreen's issue in displaying images

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I created the small,normal,large, and xl layouts and I did the
when I run the code this is the result when both are normal screen size.
If I fix one the other gets messed up or vice versa. Is their another way to solve this problem or how to.

HTC one V
[image: HTC one V]

Samsung S3
[image: Samsung 3]

The code for normal Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background1"
    android:gravity="fill_vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/pumpkin" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="500dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/righteyeoff" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:thumb="@drawable/skull" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="350dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/lefteyeoff" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use Frame/Linear Layouts. I'm still using dp's though, but in way lower numbers, which decreases the huge difference you are seeing.
I hope you still get the idea, I didn't have your images to work with so just used colors. You should be using wrap_content instead of the set widths/heights in this example.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/layout" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context=".MainActivity" android:padding="20dp">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/pumpkin" android:layout_width="200dp" android:layout_height="200dp" android:layout_gravity="center" android:gravity="center" android:background="@android:color/black">
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/leftEye" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="20dp" android:layout_height="20dp" android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" android:layout_marginRight="20dp" android:src="@android:color/holo_orange_dark" />
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/rightEye" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="20dp" android:layout_height="20dp" android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" android:src="@android:color/holo_orange_dark" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <SeekBar android:id="@+id/seekBar1" android:layout_gravity="bottom" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found that  it is very difficult to lay objects/images on top of each other using Android.

I would put things in the absolute center.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```

For the images I'd use

```
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/main_pic"
    android:layout_width="xxdip or wrap_content "
    android:layout_height="xxdip or wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true">
```

and place some on top of the others.  Maybe the eyes (still in the relative layout) in a linear layout on top of the nose.

Good luck!

Comment: You can't define an image view with an empty layout_width/height, that is illegal

Comment: I didn't write this to directly copy from. user1975060 can fill it in with whatever dip or fill he or she wants